# Integrate webstorm and perforce when project roots do not match with the workspace roots

Tags: perforce, webstorm

I have a configuration of webstorm where project roots do not match with the workspace roots, and as stated on the [man page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.1/enabling-and-configuring-perforce-integration.html?origin=old_help):

> If you specify a wrong client workspace, and your project roots do not
>   match with the workspace roots, WebStorm displays a pop-up window with
>   a warning.

```
Connection problems:

Wrong client specification:
Client roots: 
D:\projects\gobby
Actual root: 
D:/projects/idea/standard-lib
```

Is there any way to enable integration with the roots not matching?

Comment: Why not modify your Perforce workspace and change the root from `D:\projects\gobby` to `D:\projects\idea\standard-lib`? Or, create a new Perforce workspace with `D:\projects\idea\standard-lib` as its root, to use for your integration?

Comment: Because I use the workaround that is specified [here](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/43/update) to put `.idea` files into different directory